# android create arc rectangle in shape using xml

Tags: android, image

I have tried to create rectangle like this, in xml with shape but no luck, is this possible or how to transparent this image, I mean it's color want to transparent like we define color for any shape with alpha then we get transparency, is there any way for 1 of this?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this by making the color of the clipped region (a circle in my case) same to the background color.
*`float[] outerR = new float[] { 12, 12, 12, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

            float[] circleR = new float[] { 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50 };`*

```
mDrawables = new ShapeDrawable[2];
mDrawables[0] = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(outerR, null,
                null));
mDrawables[1] = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(circleR, null,
                null));
mDrawables[0].getPaint().setColor(0xFF0000FF);
mDrawables[1].getPaint().setColor(Color.GRAY);
```

And in onDraw:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);
    int x = 10;<br>
    int y = 10;<br>
    int width = 100;<br>
    int height = 100;

    for (int i = 0; i < mDrawables.length; i++) {
    Drawable dr = mDrawables[i];
    if (i == 0) {
            dr.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
            dr.draw(canvas);
        } else {
            x = 10 + 75;
            y = 10 + 75;
            dr.setBounds(x, y, x + 50, y + 50);
            dr.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
    canvas.save();
}
```

[image: It looked like this on my emuloator]